# Typescript <T extends U = U> Syntax

Tags: typescript, react-router

I'm looking at the typescript types in react-router and saw this:

```
export class Route<T extends RouteProps = RouteProps> extends React.Component<T, any> { }
```

What does the `RouteProps = RouteProps` part of the definition mean? Where can I find this in the documentation?

Comment: Section `Generic Parameter Defaults` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation at [Typescript Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

This syntax means that:

1. `T` must be extended from `RouteProps` AND
2. You can use this class providing the Generics or not:

Example:

```
interface IRoute1 extends RouteProps { }
interface IRoute2 extends RouteProps { 
    prop: string;
}
interface IOther { }

const route = new Route();
const route1 = new Route<IRoute1>();
const route2 = new Route<IRoute2>();
const routeOther = new Route<IOther>(); //this will throw an error as IOther is not extended from RouteProps
```

If you don't provide the generic interface, it'll assume the `RouteProps`.

If you provide, it must be extended from `RouteProps`.